# Sound - headset not toggling between default Speakers to Headphones when present

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, speakers, headphones

In my asusg75vw Republic of Gamers laptop (win7-64bit ultimate) my laptop is not sensing when there are headphones present. In other words it won't toggle between the default speaker settings and the headset if it's present. As a result, if I want to hear the headset at all, I have to drill down to the settings (Control Panel > Sound > and in the Playback tab change the default) Each and Every.Single.Time. I plug in my headphones to change it from speakers to headphones. If I want someone else to hear what I've just heard? I can't just unplug my earbuds but drill down thru settings Again...Every. Single. Time. Is there no way to get it to function like every other laptop I've ever had??

Comment: Is this a new laptop, or has the problem cropped up recently on an old machine?

Answer (score 0):

uninstall the sound driver and re-install it again, usually this fixes the problem